# Unity accordion UI

Tags: unity, c#, gui, ui-design

I downloaded the accordion from the unity forums and I'm trying to add a button to it. issue is with the vertical layout group. when any UI element is added the layout will automatically go vertical and scale accordingly. i fixed it by adding a layout element on the button and ticking the ignore layout option. However this generates another issue. when the UI is folded (accordion is folded) the buttons scale down and show. See image below [image: How buttons show up when folder.]  these buttons are inside section 1. and when it's opened they show up as i want. [image: accordion on] Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: so [this](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/accordion-type-layout.271818/) does not work for you ? It looks great and simple enough to integrate.

Comment: This is what im playing with right now. My issue is that when i add button inside the item it adds it to the vertical layout and scales it accordingly and I can't make anything to it. I understand this is the layout used but i want to make the flexibility of placing anything without vertical layout affection

Comment: For example now i want to add button under my item and vertical layout group is affecting and I can't do anything to button

Comment: It sounds like this question could be edited to improve it by walking us through this problem case you mentioned. Show us how you've set up your UI. Then show us how you add a button to it. Then show us what happens, and describe (or mock up / diagram) what you want to happen instead. Focusing on a specific issue like this will help attract more useful answers.

Comment: @DMGregory hi i edited the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a layout holder for your buttons that has a horizontal group layout. Note that if you want a custom group layout you will probably have to write it yourself. This screenshot shows how I set up the element. 
[image]

From there you can play with the preffered width and height of the layout element component of each button.

Hope this helps :)